# Maven parent POM maintaining versions of libraries depending on parent POM?

Tags: maven, parent-pom

I have a maven aggregate parent POM `foobar-parent` with two aggregated children, `foo` and `bar`, in the same repository.

I have another really cool library named `widgets` in another repository that depends on `foo`, for example.

Then I have many other libraries such as `example` and `app`, which may depend on `foo`, `bar`, and/or `widgets`. But they all use `foobar-parent` as their parent POMs.

The `foobar-parent` parent POM already indicates the version of `foo` and `bar` in its dependency management. But because so many libraries use `widgets`, I want to make sure all use the same `widgets` version. So would there be any problems placing `widgets` under version management in the `foo-bar` parent POM, even though `widgets` itself depends on `foo` and `bar`, and the `widgets` POM has `foobar-parent` as its parent POM?

(This shouldn't be a circular dependency, because `foobar-parent` does not define `widgets` as a dependency—it only defines its version for any library that does use `widgets` as a dependency.)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this should not be a problem, for the reasons you already mentioned.

From the organisational point of view, I would think about distinguishing the aggregator pom from the pom organising the dependencyManagement, by which I mean: You could introduce a second level of parent POMs.

Comment: One problem I foresee is that `foo-parent` would have to indicate a `widgets` version _that has not yet been released_, assuming that `widgets` itself uses `foo-parent`. And issuing another level (let's call it `foo-two-parent`) just to add `widget` seems an interesting idea, but then every time I released a new version of `foo` and/or `bar`, I would have to release a new version of `foobar-parent` _and_ `foo-two-parent`, which seems like a lot of work. Otherwise `foo-two-parent` would get stuck at an old version of `foo-parent`. I don't see any satisfactory solution here.